# Renting a dedicated, but getting a VPS. How to detect?

Tags: vps, virtual-machines, hosts, dedicated-server, guest

When renting a dedicated server, how can one be certain than he/she is not getting a VPS or some other virtual machine variant instead of a true dedicated hardware box?

Which checks can be run (assuming it is a linux box) to detect such case?

Comment: Is the provider untrustworthy? Do you feel that you need to check on this? What is your motivation for this question?

Comment: This is not regarding a specific provider, but just in general. I see cheaper and cheaper options available that I sometimes wonder if it is really a dedicated server those companies are offering.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, physical machines tend to have more memory than VPSs. Question 512MB or less. Secondly you can check several things to find a VPS. You'll commonly find virtual machines have surprisingly basic looking hardware in them. Like KVM has a "Cirrus Logic GD 5446" graphics card. VMWare used to have an RTL8129 network card in. This is so most OS installation media has drivers for the virtual devices.

The [facter](http://reductivelabs.com/products/facter/) (part of Puppet) [virtual.rb](http://github.com/reductivelabs/facter/blob/master/lib/facter/virtual.rb) script has several useful techniques for finding out what type of machine you're running.

#### OpenVZ

Look for `/proc/vz/veinfo`

#### Xen

Look for one of `/proc/sys/xen`, `/sys/bus/xen` or `/proc/xen`

#### vserver

Look for `s_context` or `VxID` in `/proc/self/status`

#### VMWare or Parallels

- Run `lspci` and look for VMWare VGA adapter
- Run `dmidecode` and look for mention of VMWare or Parallels

#### KVM

Run lspci and look for `RAM memory: Qumranet, Inc. Virtio memory balloon`

Comment: Have a vote yourself, for the KVM test which I haven't used before.

Comment: It's only cos I've got a kvm host to hand :)

Comment: Thx for the specific type of devices/hardware hints.

Answer (score 23):

There's no 100% reliable way for you to detect that you're in a VM, just like there's no way to detect whether you're actually in the Matrix, or if you're actually a computer simulation.

However, if the provider is an idiot, you can tell that you're in a VM from the following handy list:

- Xen: `/proc/sys/xen` exists
- OpenVZ/Virtuozzo: `/proc/vz` exists
- VMWare: Look for a VMWare video card in the output of `lspci`
- Linux VServer: `/proc/self/status` has an `s_context` or `VxID` field
- Solaris Zone: `/sbin/zonename` exists

These aren't 100% reliable, because the provider controls the environment and can modify the system to not show these.  However, anyone who is cheap enough to sell you a dedicated server and give you a VM probably isn't smart enough to be able to pull this off.

Comment: Damn, you got there just before I did. Have a vote :)

Comment: You too? I was certain that those green characters scrolling down the walls were only visible to me...

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at your machine's MAC address(es). Do you see any [VM-specific OUIs](http://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take a more hands-on approach, you can try this answer from [elsewhere](http://www.invisiblethings.org/papers/redpill.html).  Unfortunately, it does require a functional compiler on the "guest" system.

Answer (score -3):

Try and set up a VM environment.  It should fail if it is inside a VM.

Comment: I do not think this is correct. In the past I have seen guests being hosts for other guests, even across different virtualization platforms.

Comment: Depending on the VM environment you're in and what you're trying to do, it might not fail -- and, ultimately, the provider could have emulated everything that the VM system needs to work anyway.

Comment: It's also an awful lot of work.

Comment: I've run three VMWare ESXi hosts inside a VMWare Workstation, and then ran 5 VMWare ESXi guests inside those for doing a proof of concept. Definately not a good test.