# Identify VMWare Guest from within Linux Guest

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi

Is there somewhere from a Linux guest that will show me if the VM is running on VMWare's hypervisor?

Ideally a method that doesn't require vmware tools to be installed... maybe something in `/proc` or `/sys`?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/65718/vmware-linux-server-how-can-you-tell-if-you-are-a-vm-or-real-hardware/66798#66798 and http://serverfault.com/questions/78343/renting-a-dedicated-but-getting-a-vps-how-to-detect

Answer (score 3):

Yes, The quickest approach is to use the `virt-what` command.

```
# rpm -qf /usr/sbin/virt-what
virt-what-1.11-1.2.el6.x86_64
```

Output:

```
# virt-what 
vmware
```

But the utility also has facts for Xen, VirtualBox, KVM, Qemu, Parallels, etc.